# How to replicate sql query in spark dataframe

Tags: sql, pyspark

How to count and count distinct two variables and create a new column in DataFrame? this is from a temp view, but i would like to create from dataframe directly

My SQL query:

```
query = """
SELECT NOW() AS TODAY,
  'Main' AS SOURCE,
  'People' AS TABLE_NAME,
 COUNT(variable1,variable2) - COUNT(DISTINCT variable1,variable2) || ' ' || 'Hello' AS ERROR
  
FROM table
"""

df = spark.sql(query)
```

What I tried:

`Variable1` and `variable2` comes from another Dataframe I've created previously (`df3`), so I need to do this

```
" COUNT(variable1,variable2) - COUNT(DISTINCT variable1,variable2) || ' ' || 'Hello' AS ERROR " but using DF directly. 

data = [("Main","People")
       ]

columns = ["SOURCE","TABLE_NAME"]

df= spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df2= df.withColumn("TODAY",current_timestamp())
```

Comment: Can you provide sample input?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  You can only pass one column name to the count() aggregate function.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.count.html

Comment: I suggest you supply sample data and express what you are trying to accomplish more accurately.